# Loop runs one more time than I expected

Tags: java, loops, post-increment, pre-increment

```
class BlankIt{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10, j = 20;
        while(i++ < --j){
            System.out.println("\n " + i + " " + j);
        }
        System.out.println("\n " + i + " " + j);
    }   
}
```

The preceding output is `16 14`. Why is that happening?? The loop stops when the condition reaches `15 < 15`. Please help me out!!

Comment: You are comparing the value of `i` *before* increment with the value of `j` *after* decrement. So the comparisons are 10 < 19 (true), 11 < 18, 12 < 17, …, 14 < 15 (true) and 15 < 14 (false, causes loop to end). In the last comparison, `i` is incremented after the comparison, so the final values are 16 and 14. As you observed.

Comment: Please never use pre- or post-increment in a way where it actually matters, i.e. where you use its returned value. Try to always have it as a statement that is not used within another, in an explicit way. That way, no reader will be confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increment of `i`, being a post-increment, will occur after the comparison is evaluated, `j`, on the other hand, being a pre-decrement will occur before the comparison is evaluated:

```
10 < 19 (true)
11 < 18 ...
12 < 17 ...
13 < 16 ...
14 < 15 ...
15 < 14 (false)
```

After the evaluation of the last comparison, `i` will be incremented one more time and will have the value of `16`, `j` since it was already decremented will remain `14`.